# Using both NavigationDrawer and Tabs (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tabs

I'm building an app with some tabs and a `NavigationDrawer` on the side. My problem is I can't display the content of the fragments from my `NavigationDrawer` : when I click on it nothing happen, I still see my tabs but no new fragment.

I followed those tutorials, one is for the NavigationDrawer and the other one for the tabs, both work separately.

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

**MainActivity.java** *(Let me know if you need some more code, I'll edit my post and add it)*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_lightbulb_outline_white_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_face_white_24dp
};

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    Log.i("USER ", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString());

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        Log.d("ACTION BAR?", actionBar.toString());
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();



    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    // ...


}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            Log.i("DISPLAY VIEW", "HOME FRAGMENT DISPLAYED");
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            Log.i("DISPLAY VIEW", "FRIENDS FRAGMENT DISPLAYED");
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            Log.i("DISPLAY VIEW", "MSG FRAGMENT DISPLAYED");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}


}
```

I have the `displayView()` that should display the correct view from the `NavigationDrawer` but I also have the `tabLayout`. When I click on the differents items from the `NavigationDrawer`I have the title changing in the Toolbar but nothing more.

It is very well explained but I'm probably missing something, I know it's probabably a bit of newbie question but since it's my first Android app I guess I'm sort of one. If anyone could give a look and tell me what I should do to make those 2 work together, would be really helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: please put your code

Comment: @user3215142 let me know if you need more code, I'll add it.